# How to edit the document after uploading it on google drive using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to Google Apps Script .I want to upload document file like doc , docx and want to add more pages to it ? How can i customize uploaded document , [like add cutomized header and footer] ?

**Here is My Code**

```
function doGet(e) {

  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Upload Resume");
  var form = app.createFormPanel().setId('frm').setEncoding('multipart/form-data');
  var formContent = app.createVerticalPanel();
  form.add(formContent);  
  formContent.add(app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));
  formContent.add(app.createSubmitButton('Submit'));
  app.add(form);
  return app;
}

function doPost(e) {
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;

  var a= DocsList.FileType.DOCUMENT
  var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var label = app.createLabel('Resume uploaded successfully'+a  );
  app.add(label);

  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, when you upload a document/spreadsheet using Apps Script, it is uploaded in the same format i.e. it is not converted to Google Docs format. There is an [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1019) asking for this feature. You can star the issue to register your interest.

Comment: Is there is another way to achieve this ?